# How to validate scorm package properties upon upload?

Tags: scorm

I want to validate if a scorm package supports resuming or not once it has been uploaded into my content library. How to validate that without launching the scorm package and accessing the `cmi.suspend_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to determine this because there is no way to know which of the SCORM RTE calls will be made by a piece of content simply from the manifest, or even the included code. This is effectively the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: So the only way to validate this is by launching it in the target SCORM RTE, and then checking for the `cmi` object values?

Comment: There likely isn't a way to "validate" this unless there is only a single path through the course that the learner *must* follow and that all calls will be made each time. In that case you could test it, but as soon as there is branching logic in the course it becomes more and more difficult to examine depending on the branches chosen (think different pages visited, different answers given, in different orders, etc.). And so it also wouldn't be generic across all courses (or even a significant subset).